# Setting up Knittr workflow in Emacs

Tags: ess, r

I was a happy ESS and R user to obtain `tex` and `pdf` files from `Rnw` file with `sweave` and `knitr`. I have followed the answer given [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17063/how-to-setup-knitr-workflow-in-emacs), everything worked fine but after several updates or maybe new installation I cannot even find the `ess-sweave` customization group in Emacs. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group`: `ess-sweave` is `[No match]`.
I am using GNU Emacs 25.1.1 on Debian 9 (stable).

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)                                                                                                                                                                             
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

> packageVersion("knitr")                                                                                                                                                                                          
[1] ‘1.21
```

ESS version is 20190306.2305.

What am I missing to start to use `knitr` with ESS?

Comment: The post you linked to described an obsolete version of ESS. I've updated it to reflect the current approach supported by polymode. If you have any trouble, please leave a comment on the other question.

Comment: @Tyler, thanks for your answer, it works. As my reputation is low I cannot comment on others' posts. As a next question I would like to use natbib as a reference and I have no clue. This question is already asked; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267564/references-and-bibliography-with-knitr-ess-and-auctex