# How to specify a pdf viewer for ess mode

Tags: ess, r, polymode

I have set the variable `ess-pdf-viewer-pref` to `"evince"`

[image: Emacs Screenshot]

But when I export any `Rnw` file using `M-n e`, instead of displaying the pdf in evince it is displayed inside Emacs.

How can I stop Emacs displaying the exported pdf in a split buffer? and make it display the pdf in evince?

I am using Emacs plus ESS, polymode, and poly-R as prescribed in this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17065/21893)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use pdf-tools (pdf-view-mode) in emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19686/how-to-use-pdf-tools-pdf-view-mode-in-emacs)