# Polymode very slow in Rmd files

Tags: ess, markdown, polymode

I am struggling with emacs constantly hanging as soon as I move the cursor into a code chunk in Rmd files. It spends about two seconds moving the cursor after I hit an arrow key. Can you help me get normal response times from Emacs, so I can get back to work, please?

I used (the update) at [how to setup Knitr workflow in Emacs?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17063/how-to-setup-knitr-workflow-in-emacs) and installed ess, polymode, and poly-R from melpa. I have poly-markdown installed too.

Much less annoyingly, but still odd and maybe related, I get hundreds of buffers as I navigate through an Rmd file. They each seem to associate with tiny bits of the code in R code chunks and are named like "file.Rmd[r]<443>" where 443 is an arbitrary number. I have tried disabling minor modes to see if that should help, but due to all these buffers, I can't test if that works. If I disable a mode and hit an arrow key the buffer changes, and I think the mode is back on.

When I run a cpu profiler, go into a code chunk and try to move around a bit, the resource usage looks like this

- redisplay_internal (C function)                                5835  88%
- imenu-update-menubar                                          5819  88%
- imenu--make-index-alist                                      5819  88%
- imenu-default-create-index-function                         5819  88%
  - imenu--generic-function                                    5819  88%

  - syntax-ppss                                               5764  87%
  - syntax-propertize                                        5755  87%
  - apply                                                   5755  87%
  - pm-execute-syntax-propertize-narrowed-to-span               5755  87%
    - if                                                    5755  87%

    - condition-case                                       5755  87%
    - save-excursion                                      5755  87%
    - if                                                 5755  87%
    - progn                                             5751  87%
      - pm-map-over-spans                                5751  87%

      - save-restriction                                5751  87%
      - let*                                           5751  87%
      - while                                         5751  87%
      - let                                          4376  66%
        - pm-select-buffer                            4376  66%

        - apply                                      4368  66%
        - #<compiled 0x171e73d>                     4368  66%
        - apply                                    4368  66%
        - #<compiled 0x3ba675>                    4368  66%
          + apply                                  4368  66%
          car                                           4   0%
      - save-excursion                               1343  20%
        - funcall                                     1343  20%

        - #<lambda 0x78a6431>                        1343  20%

      - setq                                           20   0%
      - while                                           4   0%

    - let*                                                 4   0%

- funcall                                                          8   0%
  kill-this-buffer-enabled-p                                       4   0%
- tool-bar-make-keymap                                             4   0%
- ...                                                             413   6%
- command-execute                                                 345   5%
- timer-event-handler                                               4   0%
- polymode-post-command-select-buffer                               2   0%

I use Emacs 26.3 on ubuntu 20.04

This is the first lines from "C-h m"
Enabled minor modes: Auto-Composition Auto-Compression Auto-Encryption
Column-Number Cursor-Intangible Diff-Auto-Refine Eldoc Electric-Indent
Ess-Elisp-Trace Ess-Roxy File-Name-Shadow Font-Lock Global-Eldoc
Global-Font-Lock Line-Number Menu-Bar Mouse-Wheel Outline
Poly-Markdown+R Shell-Dirtrack Show-Paren Tool-Bar Tooltip
Transient-Mark

(Information about these minor modes follows the major mode info.)

ESS[R] mode defined in ‘ess-r-mode.el’:
Major mode for editing R source.  See ‘ess-mode’ for more help.

Let me know if I can provide more relevant information.

Comment: Is this still a problem for you? If so, can you tell us what version of polymode you are using? This isn't normal behaviour, it may help to update to Emacs 27 if you can.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler. I still have this issue. I think you are right I have to upgrade emacs. On a windows machine where I use emacs 27 I don't have these problems.